# Creating a bundle including a pictures with pyinstaller

Tags: python, bundle, exe, pyinstaller, specifications

I want to create a exe file from my python script, but I want  to add some pictures to the bundle. I do not know how to do it. I researched but the answer was not anywhere. I do not know how to open the spec files and how to edit them to do a one exe file including a aditional files. Please help me.

Thanks to everyone, who will respond.

Answer (score 3):

First of all you have to [create a `.spec` file](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/spec-files.html#using-spec-files). If you tried to run pyinstaller, it should have generated one already. If you want to compile with the `.spec` file, you have to use the `pyinstaller myspec.spec` command.

You can edit the `.spec` file in any text editor to add your images as [`data`](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/spec-files.html#adding-data-files). Just add them as a list of tuples, including the source file and the target directory. As per the `pyinstaller` manual example:

```
a = Analysis(...
     datas=[ ('src/img01.jpg', '.') ],
     ...
     )
```

This will add `img01.jpg` to the `.exe` folder. If you set a relative directory, you need to make sure that your script looks at the correct relative location for these files.

Comment: You have to provide some more details about what is "not working". Can you please update your question with what you've done so far (spec file, sample code, etc) and the error message you are getting?